# How to create react-native android modules using native modules?

Tags: react-native, npm

I wanted to create redis client from react native and I was going through some tutorials.

https://www.smoothterminal.com/articles/using-android-native-modules

I have built it. now I am searching/wanted to know how can i put it as service on npm ?

I wanted to know what are important files in my project and how people can use it in their project

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, upload the github project.
2. Create an account on npm.
3. Then just log in from the console to be able to load it. Upload the
   project to npm.
4. Look at the Example package.json file, so you will link the project
   that is loaded on npm with the one on github.

Example package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-native-nameproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/user/react-native-nameproject.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/user/react-native-nameproject/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/user/react-native-nameproject#readme",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react-native"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "peerDependencies": {}
```

If you put the link of your project on git, it would be better to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so i need to upload my android project directly into npm with same gradle settings ? which has app.jspn and app.js

Comment: What would be app.jspn for you?
Could you load the project on github, so I'll take a look? to help you better, if I can. ;)

Comment: Seems to be all right, I do not understand what would be your problem?